# Can I put an iframe inside a dijit Editor?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo

The Editor filters out that text. I'm willing to extend/hack/patch the Editor to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var editor = new dijit.Editor({
   extraPlugins: [
        {
            name: 'viewsource',
            stripIFrames: false    // RTFM
        }
    ]
}, this.markupEditorDiv);
```